# which version of sqlite3?

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

Environment - OS windows 10 version 1803.

```sh
python --version
Python 3.7.1  
(anaconda 3)
```

just downloaded 64-bit DLL (x64) for SQLite version 3.27.2 
https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3270200.zip

have set my path to refer to the 64 bit version above. went through and deleted other versions and verified which version of sqlite3 is being loaded within python by adding, checking python loads, deleting - checking python fails to load, then re-instating.

in python

```py
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
(3, 27, 2)
>>> print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
3.27.2
>>> print(sqlite3.version)
2.6.0
>>> print(sqlite3.version_info)
(2, 6, 0)
```

It's weird that two of the options above return version number matching the version downloaded, while two options refer to a superceded version.

I had a quick look here 
https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html

as I suspected my version of sqlite3 might include an older version if used with python 2.7.x series.  No obvious explanation to me.

ideas?

Comment: There's the sqlite version, and then there's the version of the python bindings to sqlite.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out I had some weird path issues going on. Missed updating this question when I resolved the problem and now I can't remember *exactly* how to demo the problem.

check your paths! particularly when using virtual machines and windows cmd & ubuntu shell.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3.sqlite_version is the version of SQLite.

sqlite3.version is the version of the python binding to SQLite.